# Ошибка при создании бд asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp

Создал простенький сайт на [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) + [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc). Сайт просто отображает данные из БД. При открытии сайта из под Visual Studio все отлично работает, но когда залил на IIS, то сайт начал выдавать ошибку

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database.

Использовал EntityFramework и подход CodeFirst. Строка подключения выглядит так:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StudentsContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Students.mdf';Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите куда копать.

Comment: нужно залогиниться под тем юзером, у которого есть необходимые права, попробуйте под sa

Comment: А где и как залогиниться?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что когда вы опубликовали приложение на IIS, оно у вас работает от имени пользователя, под которым запущен пул приложения.

Вы можете решить эту проблемы несколькими путями:
Плохой путь: запускать пул приложения от имени пользователя, у которого есть права на создание базы данных.

Хороший путь: Создать в базе данных учетную запись с необходимыми привилегиями,  убрать из строки подключения Integrated Security=True и добавить User Id (имя созданного пользователя) и Password (пароль созданного пользователя).

То есть в таком случае строка подключения должна быть примерно такого вида:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StudentsContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Students.mdf';User Id=username;Password=userpassword;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но не помогло. Создал пользователя бд в SQL Server management studio , прописал его в строке подключения, ошибка такая теперь "Login failed for user 'admin'"

Comment: попробуйте с этим логином залогиниться в самой SQL Server management studio, чтобы проверить, правильно ли был создан пользователь. По ошибке видно, что проблема, скорее всего, в этом логине.

Comment: Пишет невозможно подключиться ошибка 18456

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc645917(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

по моему у тебя тут не хватает **initial catalog=названиеБД;** в место AttachDbFilename(это указывает на локальную БД она создается по умолчанию вместо с проектом в папке App_Data)

ты тут походу не используешь ORM, попробуй использовать [Entity Framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/) c ним намного легче работать с любой БД